# koala Facebook events api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I'm trying to use the FB Events API (v1) to publish events which works great.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/page/events

Everything works... except, I can't get the `no_feed_post` method to work.

The Event posts perfectly, but the feed/wall post is NOT suppressed like it's supposed to be.

```
params = { name: "Blah @ #{place.name}", description: event.prizes, location: '123 Blah St.',
     start_time: Time.current, no_feed_story: true }
```

I have tried setting `no_feed_story` to:

```
true
1
"true"
t
```

Nothing seems to work... what does Facebook want?

Comment: `name: Blah @ #{place.name}"` - only one double quote?

Comment: sorry, typo just when I was copying it here ;-) but that's not the issue, all the params work fine, except `no_feed_story` which has no error, it just does nothing. ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Scanning the docs on [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/events/), they indicate these are the valid fields.

```
name
start_time
end_time
description
location
location_id
privacy_type
```

I don't see no_feed_story as a POST option

Please also make note there is a note that states:
This document refers to an outdated version of Graph API. Please use the [latest version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event)

Comment: Yeah, that could well be the case, as FB isn't great at documenting changes. But v1.0 must be in use because in v2.0 they removed publishing privileges for Events altogether!

Comment: yeah v1 is still in use.  Just pointing out in v1 i dont see your param you have listed in the docs any longer which is probably the reason it does nothing

Comment: the param isn't available for reading, it's only when you first publish the Event, in v1.0 it is still written here, it just doesn't work ;-( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/page/events